# Prevent angular routing multiple hits

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Having the following route configuration:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
          path: 'home',
          loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
    },
    {
          path: 'register',
          loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module').then((m) => 
          m.RegisterModule),
    },
    {
          path: 'forgotten-details',
          loadChildren: () => import('./forgotten-details/forgotten- 
          details.module').then((m) => m.ForgottenDetailsModule),
    },
    { 
          path: '', 
          component: SomeComponent, 
          canActivate: [SomeComponentGuard], pathMatch: 'full' 
    }
]
```

Whenever I try to hit something like `/register`, for a millisecond I can see SomeComponent, and then switch to my actual desired page `/register`, which means angular is matching first `/` and only after the `/register` part.
Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing lazy loading on the route which means the route is loaded on demand. That is why I think you first see the main route until the module is loaded because it takes some time.

One possibility to prevent this is to not lazy load the module. Another is that you use a preloading strategy to preload in advance. This means it will start loading the module immediately after the application starts to be available when needed. By default Angular provides only the [PreloadAllModules](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules) strategy which preloads all modules. If you need something different you will need to find one or write one yourself.
To add the strategy you just add it to the router configuration in the main application module.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```

Here is also a [link to the documentation about preloading in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading).

Comment: I've tried adding preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules and even tried to use eager loading, but I still see SomeComponent for a split second.

Comment: Can you put an example somewhere to see this behavior? Is this the main routing of the application? Do you go to the route by router link or directly changing address in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this object on the top of the array should solve the issue

```
{ 
         path: '', 
         component: SomeComponent, 
         canActivate: [SomeComponentGuard], pathMatch: 'full' 
    }
```

Comment: I had it on the top of the array and the behaviour is the same. That's the thing, I don't want to match this first, as I'm directly trying to access /register. I don't want to see SomeComponent for a millisecond.

Comment: useHash is true in routing.ts ?

Comment: No it's not. Should I try?

Comment: No i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you are lazy-loading every component except the `SomeComponent`. So Angular preloads it, you see it briefly and then actual route kicks in.

Have you tried adding lazyloading to `SomeComponent` as well?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
          path: 'home',
          loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
    },
    {
          path: 'register',
          loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module').then((m) => 
          m.RegisterModule),
    },
    {
          path: 'forgotten-details',
          loadChildren: () => import('./forgotten-details/forgotten- 
          details.module').then((m) => m.ForgottenDetailsModule),
    },
    { 
          path: '', 
          loadChildren: () => import('<path>').then((m) => m.SomeComponent),
          canLoad: [SomeComponentGuard] 
          canActivate: [SomeComponentGuard], pathMatch: 'full' 
    }
]
```